# How to execute sbt on Windows to open the interactive shell?

Tags: windows, scala, sbt

Whenever I type the word `sbt` in my cmd I get the following message:

[image: Error Message]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't look like you're running Cygwin, and instead using straight `cmd`. To set a variable in `cmd` you have to do `set VAR="VALUE"`. To use it, you use `%VAR%`. The syntax you're using is applicable to `sh`-compatible shells like `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: You need to run that from Bash.

Comment: How do I run this from bash?

Comment: To run bash you would need to install for example cygwin or gitsh but you do _not_ need to run bash to run sbt. Look under non-cygwin here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html

Comment: [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) might be a nice light-weight alternative to Cygwin. It seems like I preferred MSYS to Cygwin for sbt on Windows because the two handled paths differently. Cygwin requires all the windows paths to be translated to cygwin paths, whereas MSYS is OK with the windows-style paths. Something like that...

Comment: did you install and add sbt command to your system's path? you can find instructions in the [website](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `sbt` script you use is meant only for Unix environments like Linux or Unix-like environments for Windows like [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/).

Please note that you're on **Windows** so **you need the sbt scripts for Windows**.

Download the sbt installer for Windows from http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html. You may consider using [Typesafe Activator](http://typesafe.com/activator) since it's *"a browser-based or command-line tool that helps developers get started with the Typesafe Reactive Platform."*

As noted in [Under the Covers](http://typesafe.com/activator/docs) in the official documentation of Typesafe Activator:

> Activator applications use sbt under the covers. This means that
>   anything you can do in sbt you can do with an application in
>   Activator. For instance, sbt plugins can easily be added to
>   applications in Activator just like they would normally be added.

I highly recommend Typesafe Activator.

Answer (score 1):

I use https://chocolatey.org/ to install, so once you follow the instruction and have choco installed, simply run `choco install sbt` in admin powershell [choose from Windows + X]

Once that is done, open another powershell and simply run `sbt`.

I am running on Windows 10, and do remember to `choco install jdk8` as well.